# How to get parameters of nested object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to infer the parameters of a nested object that looks like this:

```
const lightSwitch = {
  off: {
    switchOn: (state: Data, payload: number) => ({
      ...state,
      state: 'on',
      meta: payload,
    }),
  },
  on: {
    switchOff: (state: Data) => ({
      ...state,
      state: 'off',
    }),
  },
};
```

I want a type, `Params`, that looks like this:

```
 {
   'switchOn': [state: Data, payload: number]
   'switchOff': [state: Data]
 }
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
type Intersect<T> = T extends { [K in keyof T]: infer E } ? E : T;

type Flattened = Intersect<typeof lightSwitch>;

type Params = { [K in keyof Flattened]: Parameters<Flattened[K]> }; // type Params = {}
```

Why is `Params` empty, and how do I correct this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TQgw8VT8gWCYUiUFBPrMgeDPRgYY+kdccBT+AtAiAA)

Comment: That's a typo, I've updated the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flattened` is a union of objects which do not share any properties. That's why `keyof Flattened` just evaluates to `never` resulting in an empty object type. We should convert this *union* to an *intersection* using the [`UnionToIntersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) type.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type GetNested<T> = UnionToIntersection<T[keyof T]>
```

The `GetNested` type will convert `typeof lightSwitch` to an object with two properties `switchOn` and `switchOff` which can be mapped.

```
type Params<T> = { 
  [K in keyof GetNested<T>]: 
    Parameters<
      GetNested<T>[K] extends infer U extends (...args: any) => any ? U : never
    > 
};

type T0 = Params<typeof lightSwitch>
// type T0 = {
//   switchOn: [state: Data, payload: number];
//   switchOff: [state: Data];
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=34&ssc=6&pln=34&pc=8#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-K2EqBC8OYyN2Sa62jELi8YbxIEg2PI1FQDrxdabJk7FDHAAM2mQnv1hs1Spk8iUFg0sSAA)

Comment: `UnionToIntersection` looks like a **very** useful type.

Comment: The only issue with this method is that it doesn't work if trying to get the parameters of a generic object, e.g.:

`type Params<T> = { [K in keyof GetNested<T>]: Parameters<GetNested<T>[K]> };`

This gives the error:

`Type 'UnionToIntersection<T[keyof T]>[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'`

Comment: @AndyJessop updated my answer to account for that